# PCLVisualizer point cloud ID

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

first the code, than the question:

```
while (!viewer.wasStopped()) {
[...get coordinates...]
if (counter = true) {
    viewer.removePointCloud("1");
    viewer.addPointCloud(point_cloud, "2");
    counter = false;
}else {
    viewer.removePointCloud("2");
    viewer.addPointCloud(point_cloud, "1");
    counter = 1;
}
viewer.spinOnce();
```

Here the question: If I run this programm, I get "[addPointCloud] A PointCloud with id <2> already exists! Please choose a different id and retry".
So my question is, if there is any possibility to free the old point cloud ID and write a new point cloud to the previous, now free, ID?

Thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9408/pclvisualizer-point-cloud-id/) by [SLAMnect](https://answers.ros.org/users/253/slamnect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2011-03-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure you did not want to write

```
if (counter == true) {
     ... code goes here
}
```

In your code snippet, you accidentally used the assignment operator in C++ and the expression always evaluates to true. Fixing that should resolve matters.

---

Originally posted by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) with karma: 960 on 2011-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1